# How to Connect Druid with ActiveMQ

Tags: druid

I am exploring druid for our data warehouse and source we have activemq, mysql and few apis.
I can easily connect with local file and kafka but how can I connect with activemq, mysql and apis in druid. And can I schedule data extraction tasks for specific time and frequency in druid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct firehose for ActiveMQ and Mysql. 
You can use Tranquility with ActiveMQ or Mysql to ingest data in druid.
https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility